# How do I use this member, declared in a header, as a function?

Tags: c++, private, member-functions

These are some parts of my crawler header file. I cannot make changes to this header file.

```
private:
    int top_position;         // The maximum position of the throttle
    bool left_reverse;        // true if left direction is reverse
    bool right_reverse;       // true if right direction is reverse
```

So I tried to implement `left_reverse` in my implementation file. This is still a stub though.

```
bool left_reverse()
 {
   return(false);
 }
```

And I use it in implementing other function.

```
double Crawler::left_engine_speed() const
{
  double speedpercentage;
  double hundred(100.0);
  speedpercentage = left_throttle.flow()*hundred;
  if(left_reverse())     // <<< HERE IT IS 
    {
      speedpercentage=speedpercentage*(-1);
    }

  return(speedpercentage);
}
```

However I receive an error telling me 
error: `'((const Vehicles::Crawler*)this)->Vehicles::Crawler::left_reverse' cannot be used as a function.` Can someone tell me the problem here?

Comment: It's been a while since I wrote C++ instead of C, but doesn't that mean it's a `bool`, not a function returning a `bool`?

Comment: @2rs2ts I am trying to use it as a bool function. But I dont know why I cannot.

Comment: I think it would be declared as `bool left_reverse();` if it was a function.

Comment: I believe so too. But it is what I was given. I am only to implement it. :(

Comment: Do you think you were supposed to just make a class that uses that as a data member...?

Answer (score 1):

It's not a function. It's a variable. There is no useful way to pretend it's a function. At all. Period.

Answer (score 0):

If the function is declared in some name space for example in the global name space then write

```
double Crawler::left_engine_speed() const
{
  double speedpercentage;
  double hundred(100.0);
  speedpercentage = left_throttle.flow()*hundred;
  if(::left_reverse())     // <<< HERE IT IS 
    {
      speedpercentage=speedpercentage*(-1);
    }

  return(speedpercentage);
}
```

or

```
if(SomeNameSpace::left_reverse())
```

Or

```
double Crawler::left_engine_speed() const
{
  bool left_reverse();
  double speedpercentage;
  double hundred(100.0);
  speedpercentage = left_throttle.flow()*hundred;
  if(left_reverse())     // <<< HERE IT IS 
    {
      speedpercentage=speedpercentage*(-1);
    }

  return(speedpercentage);
}
```

Here is a simple example

```
#include <iostream>

class Crawler
{
public:
    double left_engine_speed() const;
private:
    bool right_reverse; 
};

bool left_reverse() { return true; }

double Crawler::left_engine_speed() const
{
    if ( left_reverse() ) return 1.0;
    else return 0.0;
}

int main() 
{
    std::cout << Crawler().left_engine_speed() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. But when I put the namespace in front of it, i receive an error saying it is not a member of the namespace.